# Build error during adding Hilt to the project

Tags: android, dagger-hilt

I'm trying to add Hilt support for my MVVM project. I'm using [this tutorial](https://blog.devgenius.io/writing-viewmodel-tests-in-android-testing-fundamentals-ii-5bc44efa4a39). But I got such error:

```
Execution failed for task ':app:kaptDebugKotlin'.
> A failure occurred while executing org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.internal.KaptWithoutKotlincTask$KaptExecutionWorkAction
   > java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException (no error message)
```

my build.gradle (app):

```
buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.3.71'
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:1.8.0"
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-serialization:$kotlin_version"
    }
}

plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'
    id 'kotlin-android'
    id 'com.google.gms.google-services'
    id 'com.google.firebase.crashlytics'
    id 'kotlin-kapt'
    id 'dagger.hilt.android.plugin'
    id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.android'
}

apply plugin: 'kotlin-parcelize'
apply plugin: 'kotlinx-serialization'


android {
 ...


    compileSdkVersion 33
 ....



    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_17
        targetCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_17
    }

    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = "17"
    }
}


dependencies {
....
    implementation "com.google.dagger:hilt-android:2.45"
    kapt "com.google.dagger:hilt-android-compiler:2.38.1"
    implementation "androidx.hilt:hilt-lifecycle-viewmodel:1.0.0-alpha03"
    kapt "androidx.hilt:hilt-compiler:1.0.0"
}
```

and build.gradle for project:

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {

...

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:8.0.0'
        classpath 'org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:1.8.20'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.15'
        classpath 'com.google.firebase:firebase-crashlytics-gradle:2.9.5'
        classpath "com.google.dagger:hilt-android-gradle-plugin:2.41"
    }
}

...
```

I have such VM:

```
@HiltViewModel
class AppViewModel @Inject constructor(private val mainRepository: MainRepository) : ViewModel() {

...
}
```

with repository:

```
class MainRepository @Inject constructor(private val retrofitService: RetrofitService) {
...
}
```

and such providers:

```
@Module
@InstallIn(SingletonComponent::class)
object ApiModule {

    @Provides
    fun provideWeatherService(@ApplicationContext context: Context): RetrofitService {
        val client = OkHttpClient.Builder()
            .addInterceptor(AppInterceptor(context))
            .connectTimeout(100, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
            .dispatcher(Dispatcher().apply {
                maxRequests = 1
            })
            .readTimeout(100, TimeUnit.SECONDS).build()


        client.dispatcher.cancelAll()

        val retrofit = Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl(BuildConfig.API_URL)
            .client(client)
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
            .build()

       return retrofit.create(APIService::class.java)
    }
}
```

and also I added to my fragment:

```
@AndroidEntryPoint
class PersonalPage : Fragment(R.layout.fragment_personal_page) {
...
```

But I'm not sure that the problem is near adding class annotations. So what I need to add except these providers for getting buildable and workable project?

### UPDATE

Found in logs such error -

```
error: [Hilt]
  Unsupported metadata version. Check that your Kotlin version is >= 1.0: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unsupported metadata version. Check that your Kotlin version is >= 1.0
```

but where is kotlin version is?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So finally after huge googling I found that in some Hilt versions such problem can happen with Kotlin versions. For me the best configuration with dependencies is:

```
dependencies {
implementation "androidx.hilt:hilt-lifecycle-viewmodel:1.0.0-alpha03"
kapt "androidx.hilt:hilt-compiler:1.0.0"
kapt("org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-metadata-jvm:0.5.0")
implementation 'com.google.dagger:hilt-android:2.38.1'
kapt 'com.google.dagger:hilt-compiler:2.38.1'

.... 
}
```

with adding to classpath:

```
classpath "com.google.dagger:hilt-android-gradle-plugin:2.38.1"
```

and all started working well

Comment: You saved a life!